# Drag & Swipe in a RecyclerView List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying the ItemTouchHelper for Drag and Swipe actions in a RecyclerView List. I've used this [guide](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.us6fdj5ud) and it's working perfectly, except that i can't make the swipe activate on LongClick. I've managed to do it for the Drag action:

```
        textview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                dragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I don't know how to do it for the swipe, since it doesn't have an onStartSwipe() interface and any of my attempts to implement one, by mimicking the onStartDrag() interface, has failed.
How it can be made? Thank you for your time.

---

I've managed to implement the onStartSwipe() interface and it works by itself. However once i try to implement both drag and swipe on the same view, it acts strangely. More precisely, once i touch the view, for the entire hold down, only the drag or only the swipe animation would be activated.

Not only that, it is difficult to chose between the two actions since, it will get the first mirco movement you do to chose between either one or another.

I tried to this code for the above description:

```
        tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                return false;
            }
        });

        tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mSwipeStartListener.onStartSwipe(holder);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I also tried to use a framelayout like this:

```
        tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                return true;
            }
        });

        fl.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mSwipeStartListener.onStartSwipe(holder);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Here i drag the TextView and i swipe the FrameLayout. But since the text view is on top of the framelayout, it would only work dragging, and sometimes swipe if you touch on the corners of the item.

Any ideas on how to make both of drag and swipe work on the same item? I want to be able to either drag or swipe, once an element is LongClicked. I could use a separate ImageView for swiping and the TextView for dragging, but i'd rather not have to do that since it would ruin my design.

Comment: Why do you add the listener to the textview?

Comment: @OliverU. thats because the textview it's my row element in the RecyclerView List. Perhaps it would be better if i use a LinearView containing the TextView?

Comment: Whybdo you want longclickbehavior for swiping?

Comment: @OliverU. Because i've also got a ViewPager that need to coexist. I need longclickbehavior on list-element swing, so that it doesn't enter in conflict with the  screen slide.

Comment: How did you implement your drag vertical?

Comment: @OliverU. I used the guide's code as it is.

Comment: I struggled the same problem a while. I have a tablayout with the days of week (monday, tuesday,...). Every tab has its own recyclerlistview with drag and swipe behavior. Its true.

Comment: The only way i see to fix that: add the textview and a imageview to a layout that represents your row. If the imageview is clicked call onswipe

Comment: @OliverU. Thank you but i don't know how to implement the onswipe, since there's no interface for that. Here is the [git](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo) of the code

Comment: Ill check my code.

Comment: @OliverU. Thank you, you've also used the ItemTouchHelper utility?

Comment: Yes. I extended it to an expandable drag and swipe listview. I couldnt find a way to solve your problem yet. Ill try sunday further.

Comment: @OliverU. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes. It did not work. If you need this behavior check out advanced recyclerview. Thats a 3rd party library.

Comment: @OliverU. thank you, i'll check that out!

Comment: @OliverU. I've managed to implement the onStartSwipe() interface. But now i have some other issues. I can't get both of drag and swipe work on the same view. I've updated the post.

Comment: Yeah did it the exact same way with creating an swipeinterface. Bit I got a stupid exception I could not solve. So I stopped there. When Im home monday Ill check it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using draghelpers in recyclerview.
You can use ItemTouchHelper instead
It allows both drag and drop and swipe.

[ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html)
[SimpleCallBack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback.html)

[Tutorial for implementation](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.fylf4iif2)

Comment: then whats the issue? you are suposed to set movement flags in item touch helper and then assign touch helper to recycler viee